# Recursive DNS server test scenarios

Tags: testing, dns, bind, recursive-query, dig

I'm trying to choose the best Caching-Recursive DNS server.

Therefore I want to to know if there is a check list or test scenarios that I can use against these servers to know if they can perform as expected?

I've looked into some online tools like Infoblocks' DNS advisor pro, but it doesn't give me what I need.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: re: `I want to to know if there is a check list or test scenarios that I can use`.  By common stack exchange convention, this is not a valid question.  Voting to close

Answer (score 0):

Infoblox sells an appliance that can handle millions of queries per second and is sold into Tier 1 provider networks.  Nominum sells an even faster purpose-built appliance also sold into Tier 1 providers.  Is something like that what you're looking for?  You said "best", so you're looking at six figures $$$$$$.